# SSRS stacked column chart labels not centered

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've used SQL Reporting Services Reporting (3.0) to create a stacked column chart, everything works fine but I cant seem to get all the labels centered if they show up at all.

How would I get the labels to show in the center of the section? I understand that some of the sections are too small but most of them are large enough to fit the data in sufficiently?

There is a screen shot of the chart below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hh4rezpftl1t6eo/Graphs.jpg